# add tab to specific columns

Tags: text-processing, columns

I have the following data they are tab spaced but I discovered that some columns are not. How to make sure that the data are all tab spaced ?

here is part of the data:

```
rs987435    C   G   1   1   2   1   20
rs345783    C   G   1   1   1   1   01
rs955894    G   T   2   2   2   2   22
rs6088791   A   G   1   0   1   0   22
rs11180435  C   T   1   1   1   1   10
rs17571465  A   T   2   2   2   2   22
rs17011450  C   T   2   2   1   2   22
rs6919430   A   C   2   2   2   2   22
rs2342723   C   T   0   0   0   0   01
rs11992567  C   T   2   2   2   2   22
```

The columns starting from the 4th column should be 0,1,2 only; as you can see that the  8th column is not. I need to add tab between those numbers, how can I do that in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Linux you will have GNU Sed (as opposed to BSD Sed), and so you could simply do:

```
sed 's/.$/\t&/' file.txt
```

When satisfied with the output you see on the command line, do it "in place" (i.e. save it back to the file) with the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i 's/.$/\t&/' file.txt
```

What this does is insert a tab character before the final character on each line.

Comment: Or use `ed`, which can do the in-place editing portably just fine.

Comment: @JdeBP, well, you could also include a literal tab character in the Sed replacement string to have it be portable, but they're annoying to type (can't be copy-pasted, can't be visually confirmed to be correct).  I don't see that `ed` or `ex` has a portable way to specify a tab in the replacement string, either.

Comment: The non-portable part is not the tab character, which can be given to `ed` easily enough (it being a mistake to think that one needs special support from `ed` itself for it), but the `-i` option for the stream editor.

Answer (score -1):

Replace all spaces with tabs:

```
tr -s " " "\t" < datafile
```

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question.  Look at the example text more carefully.